# Spring JPA - Default order of the list of objects within an object

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have the following object structure:

```
class MediaPackage {

    private List<MediaAsset> mediaAssets;
    //getters,setters

}

class MediaAsset {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //getters setters
}
```

and have the Spring JPA repository media package interface:

```
@Repository
public interface MediaPackageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MediaPackage, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MediaPackage> {

}
```

I call `MediaPackage findOne()` in media package repository, what would be the default order of the list of media assets(mediaAssets) inside the returned media package object?

DB is PostgreSQL.

Comment: What would your metadata say for your List field? such as your `@OrderBy` / `@OrderColumn` annotation?

Comment: @Maddy whatever it is, don't rely on it. If you do need order, then provide `@OrderBy`

Comment: No ordering specified

Comment: @Eugene you mean it is random?

Comment: I think that if there are no special tweaks done on the Postgre; then yes it is random. But my point is different, even *if it is not random and you do see some order*; do not rely on it. It might change on the DB side without your application knowing that. And if you do need order, then provide it as such.

Comment: If no ordering is defined then they are RETRIEVED using the ID of the element as the ordering (assuming your JPA provider is compliant)

Comment: @NeilStockton thats interesting. Is there a JPA spec for that?

Comment: There is a JPA spec. It includes 11.1.42 _If the ordering element is not specified for an entity association, ordering by the primary key of the associated entity is assumed._ Note this is JPA API, *not* Spring Data JPA API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per the Spring documentation  findOne  method expect the primary key as a parameter to fetch the entity. The syntax for the findOne method from the CrudRepository as follows

T findOne(ID primaryKey);

So it Will always return the single Entity.

Comment: my question is on the object list inside the returned object